# Undefined symbol in shared library with g++

Tags: c++, qt, g++, jvmti, moc

With JVMTI I am developing an agent to profile Java applications. Therefore a shared library libagent.so is compiled. Further I use the Qt framework:

For now it consists only by these two source files:
[agent.cpp](http://pastebin.com/2u0JT3ds) and [agentserver.cpp](http://pastebin.com/t8FBLNFK)

However, when starting a Java application with my shared library libagent.so I get the error: **undefined symbol: _ZTV11AgentServer (./libagent.so)**

When I run ldd I get the same dependency problem:

```
ldd -d libagent.so 
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffeb333000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f8b6731b000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f8b67098000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f8b66e81000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8b66afe000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8b67844000)
undefined symbol: _ZTV11AgentServer (./libagent.so)
```

My current compile command is:

```
g++ $(CXXFLAGS) -fPIC -shared -o libagent.so $(INCPATH) ../src/agent.cpp ../src/agentserver.cpp
```

Where $(CXXFLAGS) is -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT $(DEFINES)

where $(DEFINES) is -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED

where $(INCPATH) is -I/home/konrad/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I../src -I/home/konrad/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/include/QtCore -I/home/konrad/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/include/QtNetwork -I/home/konrad/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/include/QtGui -I/home/konrad/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/include/linux -I. -I. -I../src -I.

I have put some time into researching this problems, but none solved this error.

---

This is the header code of the agentserver.cpp: [agentserver.h](http://pastebin.com/dsdWUgSR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that some element in AgentServer's vtable is undefined. The use of `Q_OBJECT` requires you to run `moc` on your source - and link to the qt libraries.

Comment: I declared only the constructor in the header file and I implemented it, as seen in the source code of agentserver.cpp:6-9

Comment: @platzhirsch: Post your header files

Comment: @Erik: Okay, the link to it is attached in my original post

Comment: @platzhirsch: You'll need to run moc

Comment: @Erik: As I use the Qt IDE (qmake) the moc files are generated anyway. I can easily add the needed moc...cpp files, but how do I link to the Qt library?

Comment: Pass `-lQtNetwork -lQtCore` to the g++ command - and add `-L/lib/path`

Comment: @Erik: But the Qt libraries Network and core are already included as seen in the definition of $(INCPATH) in my original post or is there a difference?

Comment: Included header files declare that functions/classes/variables exist - you need to also link to the libraries that provide the declared symbols.

Comment: @Erik: Thank you, the problem is almost solved. Two dependencies remain: _ZN11AgentSErver18incomingConnectionEi and _ZN18AgentServerHandler3runEv although I included the moc*.cpp files, any idea?

Comment: Are the two functions actually defined and not just declared in the header?

Comment: @Erik: They are both defined and declared. Is there more to include but moc_agentserver.cpp and moc_agentserverhandler.cpp ?

Comment: @Erik: http://pastebin.com/U2uQbMpK (AgentServerHandler.h) http://pastebin.com/upmryC45 (AgentServerHandler.cpp) http://pastebin.com/iYDshsS1 (AgentServer.h) http://pastebin.com/LyEGmy48 (AgentServer.cpp)

Comment: @platzhirsch: You need to link both the original .cpp's and the moc_*.cpp's

Comment: Thank you for your systematically help. It is fixed now.